# Usage of `Clipboard.js` in react throwing an error: First argument must be a String, HTMLElement,

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, clipboard, clipboard.js

I am using https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js in a react project and faing an issue in using it.

I tried using the way they explain here https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js/issues/251

I need to copy something from `input` which is read only.

here my code goes:

```
        import Clipboard from 'clipboard';
        import IconCopy from '@material-ui/icons/FileCopy';

        class CopyClass extends React.Component {

          componentDidMount () {
            const button = this.copyIcon
            const input = this.email

            this.clipboard = new Clipboard(
              button, {
                target: () => input
              }
            )
          }

          componentWillUnmount() {
            this.clipboard.destroy()
          } 

          renderUserCaption () {
            return (
              <div>
                <input 
                  ref={el => this.email = el} 
                  value={this.props.user.email}
                  type="text"
                  readOnly={true}
                />
                {document.queryCommandSupported('copy') && canCopy && (
                  <Tooltip title="Copy this email address">
                    <IconCopy 
                      ref={(el) => this.copyIcon = el}
                    />
                  </Tooltip>
                )}
              </div>
            )
          }

          render () {
            return (
              <div>
                <SomeOtherComponent
                  titleCaption={this.renderUserCaption()}
                >
                  {this.props.children}
                </SomeOtherComponent>
              </div>
            )
          }
        }
```

And I am getting error:

```
        Uncaught TypeError: First argument must be a String, HTMLElement, HTMLCollection, or NodeList
            at listen (clipboard.js:736)
            at Clipboard.listenClick (clipboard.js:183)
            at new Clipboard (clipboard.js:151)
            at UserCard.componentDidMount (index.js:107)
            at commitLifeCycles (react-dom.development.js:16227)
            at commitAllLifeCycles (react-dom.development.js:17592)
            at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:149)
            at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:199)
            at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:256)
            at commitRoot (react-dom.development.js:17788)
            at completeRoot (react-dom.development.js:19240)
            at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:19169)
            at performWork (react-dom.development.js:19077)
            at performSyncWork (react-dom.development.js:19051)
            at requestWork (react-dom.development.js:18920)
            at scheduleWork (react-dom.development.js:18729)
            at Object.enqueueSetState (react-dom.development.js:12457)
            at AsyncComponent../node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js.Component.setState (react.development.js:375)
            at AsyncComponent._callee$ (index.js:20)
            at tryCatch (runtime.js:62)
            at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js:296)
            at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (http://localhost:4000/static/js/bundle.js:17522:21)
            at step (index.js:79)
            at index.js:79
```

Where I have done wrong?

Updated code: and still the issue exist, I have now taken button itself

```
     <RootRef rootRef={(el) => this.copyIcon = el}>
        <button>
           click me
        </button>
     </RootRef>
```

Now the if I log `this.copyIcon.current` - it's catually `null`.

Comment: I don't think you can get a ref to a `FileCopy` component. Try to log the ref in `componentDidMount` and see if it's set. `console.log(button);`

Comment: Previously I made typo on copyIcon. I fixed it, still, the issue exists. 
Yes, button is - `undefined`

Comment: Alright, then I think that's the issue. You might be able to solve it by wrapping your icon in a [RootRef](https://material-ui.com/api/root-ref/).

Comment: Let me try :) Thank you

Comment: @Tholle Can you check the question again, still the error, exists. (just edited)